# Python : ORA-02399: exceeded maximum connect time, you are being logged off

Tags: python

My python code is trying to execute a couple of queries which pulls 1.2 million rows and then writing that data to a file but when query runs it takes almost 50 mins to complete the task.
After 40 mins it throws the exception as:

> ORA-02399: exceeded maximum connect time, you are being logged off

I have tried closing the connection but did not work.

```
import cx_Oracle

query1 = "SELECT col1, col2 from Table"
query2 = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 from Table"
outputFile = "file1.txt"
outputFile = "file2.txt"

def run_query(query):
    myfile = open(outputFile, 'w')
    con = cx_Oracle.connect('username/password@db-string')
    print "connected"

    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(query)
    for result in cur:
        myfile.write(str(result) + "\n")
    print "Writing done"
    con.close()

run_query(query1, file1)
run_query(query2, file2)
```

Comment: It runs fine for the first query as it pull only 2000 rows but for 2nd query which pulls 1.2 million rows it throws the above said exception.

Comment: Avoid writing to the file by looping.

Comment: @VikasP, I am writing to the file by iterating cursor object, which has to done by looping.

Comment: So for only running query  it takes 50 mins time ?

Comment: No to run and write to the file takes 50 mins.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to dumb all results to csv file.

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
fp = open('/tmp/file1.csv', 'w')
myFile = csv.writer(fp)
myFile.writerows(rows)
fp.close()
```

The time complexity of for loop is `O(log^2(n))`. So just think how much it will take for 1.2 million data. Try to avoid for loop while processing mass amount of data. here an example.

Comment: Ok let me try this.

Comment: I am still getting the same issue. I think somehow I need to maximize the connect time and make oracle allow me to connect to DB server for a bit more time.